# What happens when shiitake are exposed to sugar water?

Tags: mushrooms

I looked closely at my shiitake about 2 days after picking them, and was wondering if the fuzz on top of them is normal in the development of new buds:
[image]

within 1 day:
A few days later (the big clump was a fruiting body):
[image]

Sorry for the bad picture, but I can't get any closer with a laptop.

Comment: Could you please match the question title to the question body? What does sugar water have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

google is your friend.

"White fuzz on the ends or bark is shiitake mycelia. It's an indication that the log is trying to fruit and will not hurt anything."

https://www.shiitakemushroomlog.com/Care-Handling-s/109.htm

Comment: How do I get my kit to produce again, because it went from the fruiting stage to the fuzzy stage?

Comment: it's not a log, but a block